# Erro de conexão no composer install?

Tags: php, laravel, composer, artisan, dependências

Estou com problema ao rodar o comando `composer install` no Laravel. Sou bem iniciante no uso dele ainda, então não faço muita ideia do que poderia gerar esse erro:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
Erro na conexão, verifique o log de erro para mais informações.
> php artisan optimize
Erro na conexão, verifique o log de erro para mais informações.
```

Eu ***já deletei a pasta vendor e o composer.lock*** e tentei rodar, não deu certo. Alguém teria uma luz pra me ajudar?

Comment: Verificou o log de erro para mais informações?

Comment: Verifique os arquivos de logs que ficam em storage.